# Can't stop "SQL Server Polybase Data Movement"

Tags: sql-server, configuration, sql-server-2016, polybase

When I start Windows the "SQL Server Polybase Data Movement" service is in the "Change pending..." state and I can't close it. When I try to stop it mmc crashes.

In Windows services, the status = starting, but it never changes either. I cannot stop it here either.

Does anyone know how to stop it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PolyBase needs TCP enabled to work. By default TCP is disabled in SQL Network Configuration.